# TeamCity Build configuration parameter value

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I need to call a TeamCity Build Configuration with env.DataSource parameter daily with 2 different IP address values. I am making a call from another build configuration using snapshot dependency.

Is there a way to alter the build parameters before snapshot dependency is invoked?

Comment: There are few options, teamcity has 2 parameter types:
- runtime which are set on agent and can't be accessed outside from build chain
_ stored at configuration level  Main question would be how do plan to change parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parameters in the first build and then reference it in the second build using dependency parameters for eg `%dep.buildnum.DataSource%`.

In case you want your target to run on 2 separate IP, you can setup 2 dependent builds and each build can run on a separate IP.Please correct me if my understanding of your question is wrong here